# ZAP: Can't Execute Scripts within Zed Attack Proxy

Tags: javascript, zap

I try to execute the community script "Extender/HTTP Message Logger.js". I first double click on the script to make it open in the scripting console. However, in the scripting console, the "Execute" button is disabled and I see no other way how to make it run.

What am I missing?

Comment: Post it on stackoverflow, you should have better luck there. I post all my zap questions there and Simon Bennet has been pretty good at responding, what a guy:)

Comment: Thanks @postoronnim :) For info this has now been answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597544/zap-execute-script

Answer (score 1):

You don't execute Extender scripts, they're either installed (Enabled) or not (Disabled). Read through the code of the [Message Logger](https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/blob/master/extender/HTTP%20Message%20Logger.js), it's meant to write traffic to disk (in its default form, only JSON traffic).